# Excel 2016 Power Query - Expanding a fixed list like you do a record

Tags: microsoft-excel, json, power-query

I am using Power Query to Get Data from a json file.  The elements in my json file that come up as "Record" I can expand the fields inside, all good.  But some of the elements come up as "List".  Now these lists are fixed, in that they always contain 3 elements, no more, no less.  So IMO they don't really need to be lists, but I have to work with it.

Here is the JSON

```
{
    "start":0,
    "limit":10,
    "count":2,
    "records":[
        {
            "id":2024,
            "customerNo":"XTEST",
            "name":"Abso Clean Industries",
            "hold":false,
            "status":"A",
            "creditType":1,
            "creditLimit":"0",
            "creditBalance":"0",
            "creditApprovedBy":null,
            "creditApprovedDate":null,
            "openOrders":"0",
            "lastInvoiceDate":null,
            "specialCode":" ",
            "lastYearSales":"0",
            "thisYearSales":"0",
            "nextYearSales":"0",
            "lastYearGP":"0",
            "thisYearGP":"0",
            "nextYearGP":"0",
            "currency":"",
            "userDef1":"",
            "userDef2":"",
            "created":"2020-04-11T17:39:54.901022",
            "modified":"2020-04-11T17:39:54.901022",
            "invoiceType":"F",
            "statementType":"F",
            "applyFinanceCharges":false,
            "averageDaysToPay":"0",
            "lastPaymentAmt":"0",
            "lastPaymentDate":null,
            "reference":null,
            "poRequired":false,
            "paymentTerms":{
                "code":null,
                "description":null
            },
            "foregroundColor":0,
            "backgroundColor":16777215,
            "discount":"0",
            "receivableAccount":"11210",
            "defaultShipTo":"",
            "upload":false,
            "lastModified":"2020-04-11T17:39:54.887023",
            "address":{
                "line1":"5705 N Lincoln Ave",
                "line2":"",
                "line3":"",
                "line4":"",
                "city":"Chicago",
                "postalCode":"60659",
                "provState":"IL",
                "country":"USA",
                "phone":{
                    "number":"7732759089",
                    "format":1
                },
                "fax":{
                    "number":"",
                    "format":1
                },
                "contacts":[
                    {
                        "name":"Abram Midkiff"
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"John Smith"
                    },
                    {
                        "name":""
                    }
                ],
                "territory":{
                    "code":"",
                    "description":""
                },
                "salesperson":{
                    "code":"",
                    "name":""
                },
                "salesTaxes":[
                    {
                        "code":1,
                        "exempt":""
                    },
                    {
                        "code":2,
                        "exempt":""
                    },
                    {
                        "code":0,
                        "exempt":""
                    },
                    {
                        "code":0,
                        "exempt":""
                    }
                ],
                "shipCode":"",
                "shipDescription":"",
                "sellLevel":1,
                "email":"",
                "defaultWarehouse":"VA"
            },
            "links":{
                "self":"https://localhost:10880/api/v2/companies/INSPIRE33/customers/2024"
            }
        },
        {
            "id":2025,
            "customerNo":"XTEST2",
            "name":"ABC Electronics",
            "hold":false,
            "status":"A",
            "creditType":1,
            "creditLimit":"0",
            "creditBalance":"0",
            "creditApprovedBy":null,
            "creditApprovedDate":null,
            "openOrders":"0",
            "lastInvoiceDate":null,
            "specialCode":" ",
            "lastYearSales":"0",
            "thisYearSales":"0",
            "nextYearSales":"0",
            "lastYearGP":"0",
            "thisYearGP":"0",
            "nextYearGP":"0",
            "currency":"",
            "userDef1":"",
            "userDef2":"",
            "created":"2020-04-11T17:40:58.794062",
            "modified":"2020-04-11T17:40:58.794062",
            "invoiceType":"F",
            "statementType":"F",
            "applyFinanceCharges":false,
            "averageDaysToPay":"0",
            "lastPaymentAmt":"0",
            "lastPaymentDate":null,
            "reference":null,
            "poRequired":false,
            "paymentTerms":{
                "code":null,
                "description":null
            },
            "foregroundColor":0,
            "backgroundColor":16777215,
            "discount":"0",
            "receivableAccount":"11210",
            "defaultShipTo":"",
            "upload":false,
            "lastModified":"2020-04-11T17:40:58.779279",
            "address":{
                "line1":"123 Main Street",
                "line2":"",
                "line3":"",
                "line4":"",
                "city":"Chicago",
                "postalCode":"60659",
                "provState":"IL",
                "country":"USA",
                "phone":{
                    "number":"7732759089",
                    "format":1
                },
                "fax":{
                    "number":"",
                    "format":1
                },
                "contacts":[
                    {
                        "name":"Jane Smith"
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"Mary Smith"
                    },
                    {
                        "name":""
                    }
                ],
                "territory":{
                    "code":"",
                    "description":""
                },
                "salesperson":{
                    "code":"",
                    "name":""
                },
                "salesTaxes":[
                    {
                        "code":1,
                        "exempt":""
                    },
                    {
                        "code":2,
                        "exempt":""
                    },
                    {
                        "code":0,
                        "exempt":""
                    },
                    {
                        "code":0,
                        "exempt":""
                    }
                ],
                "shipCode":"",
                "shipDescription":"",
                "sellLevel":1,
                "email":"",
                "defaultWarehouse":"VA"
            },
            "links":{
                "self":"https://localhost:10880/api/v2/companies/INSPIRE33/customers/2025"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Here the Power Query code I generated.

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\peter\OneDrive\Desktop\JsonTest.txt")),
    records = Source[records],
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(records, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"id", "customerNo", "name", "hold", "status", "creditType", "creditLimit", "creditBalance", "creditApprovedBy", "creditApprovedDate", "openOrders", "lastInvoiceDate", "specialCode", "lastYearSales", "thisYearSales", "nextYearSales", "lastYearGP", "thisYearGP", "nextYearGP", "currency", "userDef1", "userDef2", "created", "modified", "invoiceType", "statementType", "applyFinanceCharges", "averageDaysToPay", "lastPaymentAmt", "lastPaymentDate", "reference", "poRequired", "paymentTerms", "foregroundColor", "backgroundColor", "discount", "receivableAccount", "defaultShipTo", "upload", "lastModified", "address", "links"}, {"Column1.id", "Column1.customerNo", "Column1.name", "Column1.hold", "Column1.status", "Column1.creditType", "Column1.creditLimit", "Column1.creditBalance", "Column1.creditApprovedBy", "Column1.creditApprovedDate", "Column1.openOrders", "Column1.lastInvoiceDate", "Column1.specialCode", "Column1.lastYearSales", "Column1.thisYearSales", "Column1.nextYearSales", "Column1.lastYearGP", "Column1.thisYearGP", "Column1.nextYearGP", "Column1.currency", "Column1.userDef1", "Column1.userDef2", "Column1.created", "Column1.modified", "Column1.invoiceType", "Column1.statementType", "Column1.applyFinanceCharges", "Column1.averageDaysToPay", "Column1.lastPaymentAmt", "Column1.lastPaymentDate", "Column1.reference", "Column1.poRequired", "Column1.paymentTerms", "Column1.foregroundColor", "Column1.backgroundColor", "Column1.discount", "Column1.receivableAccount", "Column1.defaultShipTo", "Column1.upload", "Column1.lastModified", "Column1.address", "Column1.links"}),
    #"Expanded Column1.address" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Column1", "Column1.address", {"line1", "line2", "line3", "line4", "city", "postalCode", "provState", "country", "phone", "fax", "contacts", "territory", "salesperson", "salesTaxes", "shipCode", "shipDescription", "sellLevel", "email", "defaultWarehouse"}, {"Column1.address.line1", "Column1.address.line2", "Column1.address.line3", "Column1.address.line4", "Column1.address.city", "Column1.address.postalCode", "Column1.address.provState", "Column1.address.country", "Column1.address.phone", "Column1.address.fax", "Column1.address.contacts", "Column1.address.territory", "Column1.address.salesperson", "Column1.address.salesTaxes", "Column1.address.shipCode", "Column1.address.shipDescription", "Column1.address.sellLevel", "Column1.address.email", "Column1.address.defaultWarehouse"})
in
    #"Expanded Column1.address"
```

The issue is with the Contact Names.  I want fields ContactName1, ContactName2, ContactName3.
I could not find a way using the Excel user interface to accomplish this.
So I think I need to edit the Power Query code, but need help on this.

Peter

Comment: If those names are all you want, just expand (drill down), expanding only the relevant columns.  Looks like `address` → `contacts`

Answer (score 0):

If what you want are the contact names, you can just keep expanding.  In the UI, you would select the double arrow at the top of the column.  For a `List`, you'd probably want to expand to new rows.

Eg: (for the contact names):

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\Ron\Desktop\myFile.json")),
    records = Source[records],
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(records, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"address"}, {"address"}),
    #"Expanded address" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Column1", "address", {"contacts"}, {"contacts"}),
    #"Expanded contacts" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded address", "contacts"),
    #"Expanded contacts1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded contacts", "contacts", {"name"}, {"name"})
in
    #"Expanded contacts1"
```

Comment: I see in your code there is a "ExpandListColumn"  that's what I need.  I just can't figure out how to get the UI to do this.  ExpandRecordColumn is so easy with the UI.  So I'm trying to understand the syntax structure of 'let"  "in"  so I can work ExpandListColumn into my existing code (I want all the columns I had PLUS these new 3 columns.  It's not very intuitive, coming from an SQL background.

Comment: I now understand you code.  It gives me multiple rows and excludes all the other data I want.  Essentially, I want to transpose the list into numbered columns.  I want all the data I had in my original example, plus 3 extra columns called ContactName1, ContactName2, ContactName3.  Is this possible?

Comment: In Power Query, you'd have to expand all the expandable columns. That can get tedious. If you do an Internet search for something like `Power Query ExpandAll` and/or `Power Query ExpandAllRecords`, you'll get some ideas of how to program a recursive routine in Power Query to do that.